# Passing a parameter from navigation to page in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a user profile page that I need to navigate to two different ways. One way is by the bottom navigation bar. This will take the user to the page and populate all the text fields with their information.

The other way is by the sidedrawer navigation. This is how the current user can add a new user so when the user navigates to the user profile screen all the text fields will be empty.

So, I need a way to pass a parameter to the user profile screen telling if the user is coming from the bottom navigation bar or the sidedrawer navigation.

Right now, I pass "true" if the user is coming from the sidedrawer and I set a globalNotifierProvider value to "false" if the user is coming from the bottom navigation.

All the navigation code is in the Main_screen.dart file. This is the code below:

```
class MainScreenState extends ConsumerState<MainScreen> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userFName = ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).fName;
    userLName = ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).lName;
    userEmail = ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).email;
  }

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
      body: Container(child: appScreens[_pageIndex]),
      drawer: const SideDrawer(ref), <<< TRYING TO PASS ref BUT THIS IS WRONG
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = value;
          });
          if (value == 3) {
            ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false); <<<  PASSING BY STATE HERE
          }
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined), label: "Trxn"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: "Calendar"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "User Profile"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: 'Chat'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  void setIndex(int index) {
    if (mounted) setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
  }
}

class SideDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideDrawer(Ref ref, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: (ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text("${userFName} ${userLName}"),
            accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser!.email ?? 'No Email Found'),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.add_business,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Add Company'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const CompanyScreen(true)));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Add User'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  ref
                      .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                      .updateNewUser(true); <<<  TRYING TO USE STATE TO PASS BUT I GET AN ERROR
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const UserProfileScreen(true),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.calculate,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Mortgage Calculator'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              const MortgageCalculatorScreen()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.calculate,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Pricing'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              const MortgageCalculatorScreen()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                title: const Text('Log Out'),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  signOut();
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```

In the user profile screen I receive the passes parameter from the sidedrawer menu item like this:

```
class UserProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'user_profile_screen';
  final Users? users;
  final bool isNewUser;

  const UserProfileScreen([this.isNewUser = true, this.users]);

  @override
  ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}
```

The problem with this code is that isNewUser is always true because I get an error if I don't initialize it.

What is the best way to pass a parameter from the navigation items to the user profile page so I can implement both scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should works with isNewUser optional and check true value to populate user informations

```
class UserProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'user_profile_screen';
  final Users? users;
  final bool? isNewUser;

  UserProfileScreen({this.isNewUser, this.users});

  @override
  ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}
```

and

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfileScreen(isNewUser:null))
```